# How to only get the number of lines of a file

Tags: linux, bash

How do I get the number of lines of a file in linux?

I only want the number of lines, not the filename.
I want to do it in a single command, without grep or another utility.

```
wc -l sample.txt
```

**Output**

```
5 sample.txt
```

**Desired Output**

```
5
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this

```
wc -l < sample.txt
```

`wc` doesn't print out the filename if it reads the file through standard input. The `<` feeds the file via standard input.

Answer (score 3):

Other *single* commands to get the number of lines in a file without filename.

`sed`:

```
$ sed -n '$=' filename
```

`awk`:

```
$ awk 'END{print NR}' filename
```

Comment: These are nice as they don't have extra whitespace. However, the sed command doesn't give `0` if the file is empty.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to strip the whitespace out too, use `sed`.

```
wc -l < file | sed 's/ //g'
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternate command to print number of lines without whitespace:

```
awk 'END{print NR}' sample.txt
```

OR using grep:

```
grep -c '^' sample.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
cat sample.txt | wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the output into a variable try this:

```
VAR=$(wc -l < sample.txt); echo ${VAR}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also do

```
wc -l test.txt | cut -d" " -f1
```